# SwiftUI Is there a way to override the default back button in the navigation view toolbar without needing to add a modifier to every secondary view?

Tags: swiftui

I know that on the view you can add the following modifiers to modify the navigation bar to create a custom back button.

```
    SomeView{ ... }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Button {
                mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
            }
        }
```

However, I do not want to go through my entire app to every secondary view and add these modifiers. I've considered creating a reusable header component, but at the moment, I'm just wondering if there was a way to override the system default for the back button to impact the entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately In `SwiftUI` there is not. You could however, override `UINavigationController` but it is not recommended as `APIs` can change.

Look at List for example, we used to set the `UITableView` appearance background color to `.clear` to customize `List's` background, but in iOS 16 this solution works no more.

Extended `View` and create a func where you put your code in it, then use that function wherever you need!

Answer (score 0):

This UIKit override is working for me in iOS 16 (Although back button text might be misaligned):

```
@main
struct TestApp: SwiftUI.App {
    
    init() {
        // Back button
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        if let image = UIImage(named: "arrow.back") {
            navBarAppearance.backIndicatorImage = image
            navBarAppearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
        }
    }
...
}
```

And the native swiping pattern also works with this override in App file (found on another StackOverflow article):

```
/// Prevents custom back button dismiss actions from preventing native swiping interactions (i.e. swipe to go back)
    extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        override open func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        }
    
        public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return viewControllers.count > 1
        }
    
        // To make it works also with ScrollView
        public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            true
        }
    }
```

Comment: The UIAppearance trick seems to be no longer working with the new NavigationStack that was introduced in iOS 16.